# mysql use stored procedure out variable result in another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two Stored procedures one and two
I need to call procedure one from procedure two
In procedure two I need to read output variable from procedure one for use them in one IF condition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `one`(
  IN invar_one VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar_one VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE query_result VARCHAR(32);
  SELECT hash INTO query_result FROM my_table WHERE hash = invar_one;

  IF (invar_one = query_result) THEN
    SET outvar_one = "OK";
  ELSE
    SET outvar_one = "NOT OK";
  END IF;
END;


CREATE PROCEDURE `two`(
  IN invar_two VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar_two VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN   
  CALL one(invar_two,@outvar_one);
  IF (@outvar_one = "OK") THEN
    SET outvar_two = "OK";
  ELSE
    SET outvar_two = "NOT OK";
  END IF;
```

END;

If I call first procedure (one) outvar_one result is correct

```
CALL one(:invar,@outvar);
SELECT @outvar as result  //result = OK or NOT OK
```

But if i call the second the outvar_two result is empty

```
CALL two(:invar,@outvar);
SELECT @outvar as result  //expected OK or NOT OK string but is empty
```

**UPDATE EDIT: [SOLVED]**

The above example running OK.
I have one typo in mi test script.

Comment: You have not declared `@outvar_one` in the second stored procedure.  This looks like a typo.

Comment: While, as a session variable, `@outvar_one` doesn't really need declared or initialized; you might be better off if you used a local variable in the body of `two`; doing so will at very least eliminate one possible cause of the problem, and session variable should generally be avoided in stored procs and the like as much as is reasonably possible (since they are effectively "global" on the connection).

Comment: +Gordon Linoff True this had one typo  but not in my question... bfff I have write correct my question but i have one typo error in mi test script
+Uueerdo Yes You have reason Do'nt need to declare it
Now run ok. Thank you.